# css cannot delete spaces between images

Tags: css

I have 9 images inside one div. There are spaces between lines (please see the image below). I need to delete them. Could you please help me.

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
                <img src=".../1.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../2.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../3.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../4.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../5.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../6.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../7.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../8.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;"><!--
                --><img src=".../9.jpg" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;">
</div>
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle with your CSS included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, but one very quick way in your case, since the container `div` doesn't have any text in it, is to do this:

```
div { /* your inline images container div with no text */
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This will make the existing white space between your inline `img` elements not occupy any space in the rendered layout.

But even if you are going to have text inside this `div`, simply restore the text size for the elements containing the text, e.g. for a `span` inside this `div`:

```
div span {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: great, it works :) but what if I will need to add text on those images later. Do you have another solution for that case?

Answer (score 3):

You've got your images on separate lines. The linebreak chars ARE treated by browsers as whitespace, e.g.

```
<img>[linebreak char here]
<img>
```

is rendered as

```
<img> <img>
     ^---- linebreak converted to space
```

If you want them against each other exactly, you'll have to eliminate the whitespace:

```
<img><img><img>...
     ^--no space at all
```

Comment: great solution Marc, thanks. Now I have 3 lines in the div and there are 3 images on each line and there are no spaces between images. The only problem is that there are spaces between lines. Please check my updated question with image in it.

Comment: if you want them to be on their own lines, you can also do something like `<img><!--[line break]--><img><!--[line break]--><img>`... etc.

Comment: put forced `margin:0;padding:0;border:0` on them. each image could be treated as an in-line `<p>` or whatever, with whitespace below them.

Comment: I put that on div and on each image but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the images either on one line:

```
<div>
   <img src="img1.jpg"><img src="img2.jpg"><img src="img3.jpg"><img src="img4.jpg">
</div>
```

Or use an html comment:

```
<div>
   <img src="img1.jpg"><!--
--><img src="img2.jpg"><!--
--><img src="img3.jpg"><!--
--><img src="img4.jpg"><!--
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you having images stock on top of each other ? Usually there is a 3px margin between them. Setting their styling to display:block fixes this.